# Django-cms show_menu error: 'function' object has no attribute 'compile'

Tags: django, django-cms

I am in the process of upgrading a Django-CMS project one release at time.  Everything is working on Django 1.6.11/Django-CMS 3.0.15 (running Python 2.7.11 in a virtualenv on Ubuntu).

When upgrading to Django 1.7.1/Django-CMS 3.0.15 the show_menu tag throws an error. `show_breadcrumb` also throws the same error.  I can remove the `show_menu` tag and the pages render correctly.  I have `load menu_tags` before `show_menu` in `base.html`.

The error in debug mode gives

```
 Exception Value: 'function' object has no attribute 'compile'
 Exception Location:    /ebs/dcenvironmental/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/where.py in as_sql, line 106
```

I have no idea what is causing this error.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is '1.7.1' a typo (for 1.7.11)?

Comment: No.  But I have tried both versions.  Same error.

Comment: A big thanks to czpython helping fix the issue over at https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/5267 .

The issue was the django-tagging version I was using. I had django-tagging==0.3.1. Zinnia requires django-tagging>=0.3.6. Upgrading to 0.3.6 fixed the issue.

Thank you for all the help and pointing me to look at my requirements with Zinnia and tagging! I already applied the bug fix for zinnia but forgotten about the error it first caused.